# Error while fetching data from GitHub API

Tags: github, fetch-api, github-api

I'm trying to get user details from the Github API using fetch, but it's showing the following error in the console

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.github.com/users/a' from origin
>   'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

How to solve this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Comment: strange, can you try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marvel92/bn19qfju/1/) does it show an alert with the result ?

Answer (score 0):

Even if the error message includes "CORS", there are other things wrong.

---

The following content that is my original answer has nothing with this question.

> It is the problem of the browser and localhost **not GitHub API**.
> (To tell the truth, GitHub API allow CORS)
> Normal browsers must disturb the connection between localhost and http(s)://*.
> If you want to avoid it, you should use http-server (`npm install http-server -g`).

Comment: Sorry, I've mistaken! Even from localhost, CORS is not important.
Even if the error message includes "CORS", there are other things wrong.